# Node.js saving session using Redis store

Tags: node.js, session, express, redis

I am facing an issue with handling session using latest version of Express, Node.js. 
My requirement is to store users email id in /login route, and need to get that email id thought out 
all routes like /home. But email id is not printing in /home route with my current code. Your help is much appreciate.

My demo code is here

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var session = require('express-session');
var RedisStore = require('connect-redis')(session);
app.set('port',process.env.PORT || 3000);
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(session({
    resave: false,
    saveUninitialized: false,
    store: new RedisStore({
      host: 'localhost',
      port: 6379
    }),
    secret: 'some string/hash secret'
}));


var counter=0;
app.get('/login', function(request, response){
  //adding some value to request.session
  request.session.email = 'jak@amt.in';
  console.log('sessionID', request.sessionID)
  response.send('email: '+request.session.email);

});
app.get('/home', function (request, response) {
  console.log('home login', request.session.email); // Email not priting here 
  console.log('sessionID - home', request.sessionID); // Session ID is showing 
  response.send('home');
});

if (!module.parent) {
    console.info('Listening ', process.env.PORT || 5000);
    app.listen(process.env.PORT || 5000);
}
module.exports = app;
```

I am getting following error

```
"ReplyError: ERR wrong number of arguments for 'set' command
    at parseError (/home/dibeesh/obpnode6/testproject/node_modules/redis/node_modules/redis-parser/lib/parser.js:161:12)
    at parseType (/home/dibeesh/obpnode6/testproject/node_modules/redis/node_modules/redis-parser/lib/parser.js:222:14)"
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your **redis server** is running when you run your app.

Comment: Thank you..it is running. Also tried to save redis session in to heroku db. But same error.

Comment: I think your **redis server** version is old.If so , try some recent version. See below link,https://github.com/tj/connect-redis/issues/165